# CUDA cache mechanism behavior for stores with a simple mem-filling kernel

Tags: caching, architecture, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

Suppose I have below CUDA kernel, launched with 256 blocks each having 256 threads. `nElem` is `256*256`, and `elems` is allocated in device global memory. The device is cache-enabled (Fermi or above), and UVA is in effect. As you can see `elems` is NOT `volatile`.

```
__global__ void simpleGPUKernel(int* elems, int nElem) {
    unsigned int tid = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    for ( unsigned int i = tid; i < nElem; i += blockDim.x*gridDim.x){
        elems[ i ] = i;
    }
}
```

1. Based on my understanding, at the end of each block, because there's no data dependency, syncing or fencing, the time when L2 updates the device memory cannot be determined, and mostly depends on cache size (because of LRU policy) and the memory access frequency caused by other threads. Am I correct?
2. Because there's no necessity to wait for the actual memory address to be updated quickly, after `elems[ i ] = i;` instruction, SM warp scheduler, without being concerned about the actual device memory updated or not, runs further instructions from the warps in the block (in above case addition and comparison in the `for` loop), ends the block, and allocates another block for recently-freed resources. During described procedure, SM is enjoying Instruction Level Parallelism, and there's no guaranty that `elems[ i ]` in device memory is updated. Am I correct about this?
3. If Anything is cached in L1, it has to be updated in L2 before the life-span of the block finishes. Is this correct?
4. Apart from the speed associated with updating the actual memory from L2, is there any difference in above described procedures if the allocated memory is in the host memory or in a peer device global memory?

Comment: Details of L1, L2 will vary from  NVidia device family to device family.  Is there a specific problem with CUDA, are you getting a wrong result  or unexpected behavior?  What problem are you trying solve?  There are established patterns like atomic operations, fences and barriers to ensure memory  consistency at various points?

Comment: @TimChild There's no problem except that I'm not sure about items above. In my opinion, such understanding of underlying hardware is important because they can help us come up with faster CUDA programs that exploit ILP by covering latency associated with write instructions.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, on bullets 1 and 2, you are correct.

For your bullet 3, the data in L1 does not have to be written back to L2 after the block (by block, I believe you meant threadblock) finishes. The reason is, all write accesses always go to L2, invalidating the possibly present data in L1.

For your bullet 4. No, I don't think there is any difference.

Comment: About 3: Why do you claim all write accesses always go to L2? Aren't you assuming all writes are `st.cg` instructions?